# Is it possible to create any linear transformation matrix for a set of input vectors and a set of output vectors?

Tags: linear-transformations

For some field $F$, given a set of $n$-dimensional input vectors $V_{in}$ and a set of $n$-dimensional output vectors $V_{out}$, where each of the set does not contain any duplicated elements.

Is it possible to create a corresponding linear transformation matrix $M$ such that $\vec{v}_{out} = M \vec{v}_{in} $ where $\vec{v}_{in} \in V_{in}, \vec{v}_{out} \in V_{out}$?

$M:F^n \rightarrow F^n$

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. Suppose we are in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $. Let $ V_{\text{in}} = \{ (1, 0), (2, 0) \} $, $ V_{\text{out}} = \{ (1, 0) \} $. Then if a linear transformation $ T $ satisfied this property, we would have $ T((1, 0)) = T((2, 0)) = (1, 0) $. Then by linearity, we would also have $ T((1, 0)) = T((2, 0)) - T((1, 0)) = (0, 0) $, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! What if the number of vectors contained in each set is the same?

Comment: This would still not hold. Let $ V_{\text{out}} = \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\} $, $ V_{\text{in}} as above. By linearity, $ 2 T((1, 0)) = T((2, 0)) $, so $ T[V_{\text{in}}] $ will be linearly dependent. The issur with the image having one element was discussed in my answer. As $ V_{\text{out}} $ is linearly independent, the image cannot be $ V_{\text{out}} $, so we again have a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The image will either be a singleton or linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V_{\text{in}}$ be an ordered set of $n$ vectors of $F^n$. Then the assertion “for every ordered set $V_{\text{out}}$ of $n$ vectors of $F^n$, there is a linear transformation $T\colon F^n\longrightarrow F^n$ such that $T$ maps the $k$<sup>th</sup> element of $V_{\text{in}}$ into the $k$<sup>th</sup> element of $V_{\text{out}}$” is equivalent to the assertion that $V_{\text{in}}$ is a basis of $F^n$.